# writing a publisher and subscriber and unsure how to finish it

Tags: ros, python, subscribe, publish, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am taking this edx course on robotics using ROS and our first project is "writing a node that subscribes to a topic and publishes to another. Your code will subscribe to a topic called 'two_ints', on which a custom message containing two integers can be broadcast. Make sure to familiarize yourself with the message format of this topic:

```
int16 a
int16 b
```

. Those two integers are to be added and the result published to topic 'sum' as an Int16 from std_msgs. "

ok this is what I have so far from stringing other examples I have seen together and guessing... very lost now though about how to connect these and also what the 'callback' thing does or if I need to define that..

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
import rospy

from std_msgs.msg import Int16
from project1_solution.msg import TwoInts
  
def listener():
 rospy.init_node('project1_solution', anonymous=True)
 rospy.Subscriber("two_ints", TwoInts, callback)
 rospy.spin()
 
while not rospy.is_shutdown():
  msg = TwoInts()
  solution = msg.a + msg.b
  
 
def talker():
 pub = rospy.Publisher('Sum', Int16, queue_size=10)
 rospy.init_node('project1_solution', anonymous=True)
 rate = rospy.Rate(0.5) #.5hz



 while not rospy.is_shutdown():
  msg = Int16()
  
  pub.publish(msg)
  rate.sleep()
```

thank you, any tips or help would be great!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271224/writing-a-publisher-and-subscriber-and-unsure-how-to-finish-it/) by [moonspacedancer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31680/moonspacedancer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2017-09-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-20**:
How far have you gotten with the [official tutorials found on the wiki?](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials)

**Comment by [moonspacedancer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31680/moonspacedancer/) on 2017-09-20**:
@jayess, I have completed 1-20 plus beginning tf tutorials and some urdf tutorials now. also reading 'gentle introduction to ROS'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a package (**my_pkg**) with two nodes, trying to reproduce your situation.. It is like that:

```
catkin_create_pkg my_pkg rospy std_msgs message_generation message_runtime
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(my_pkg)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  message_generation
  message_runtime
  rospy
  std_msgs
)

add_message_files(
  FILES
  two_ints.msg
)

generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs
)

catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES my_pkg
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS message_generation message_runtime rospy std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

**package.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>my_pkg</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The my_pkg package</description>
  
  <maintainer email="user@todo.todo">user</maintainer>
  
  <license>TODO</license>
  
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
  
  <export>

  </export>
</package>
```

The message file **msg/two_ints.msg**

```
int16 a
int16 b
```

The publisher node (that publishes the two_ints message) **scripts/publisher_two_ints.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy

from my_pkg.msg import two_ints

def main():
    rospy.init_node("two_ints_publisher")
    pub = rospy.Publisher("two_ints", two_ints, queue_size=1)
    r = rospy.Rate(1)
    
    msg = two_ints()
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        msg.a = 2
        msg.b = 15
        pub.publish(msg)
        r.sleep()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

And finally, the one you are interested, the subscriber, which calculates the sum and publishes the result into the */sum* topic: (**subscriber_two_ints.py**)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy

from my_pkg.msg import two_ints
from std_msgs.msg import Int16

result = Int16()

def callback(msg):
    result.data = msg.a + msg.b
    rospy.loginfo(result)

def main():
    rospy.init_node("two_ints_subscriber")
    pub = rospy.Publisher("sum", Int16, queue_size=1)
    sub = rospy.Subscriber("two_ints", two_ints, callback)
    r = rospy.Rate(1)
    
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        pub.publish(result)
        r.sleep()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

Basically, you have a publisher and a publisher+subscriber. It's common to have a node with both, you have to handle the loop rate and the callback methods and be careful to not freeze inside your loop.

You can check the development, step-by-step in this video: https://youtu.be/H6bw5aw9mOQ

I hope it can help you!

---

Originally posted by [marcoarruda](https://answers.ros.org/users/25735/marcoarruda/) with karma: 541 on 2017-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-06**:
Please do not suggest writing the subscriber in this way. There is absolutely no need to run your own `while` loop here, or to continuously publish `result`.